SseEmitter completeWithError leads to "transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining" in curl
I want to use SseEmitter in a Spring Boot (version 3.3.5) application. My test code looks like this:
    private final ExecutorService nonBlockingService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    @GetMapping(path="/TEST")
    public SseEmitter test() {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        nonBlockingService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                emitter.send("this is a great first test");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            emitter.completeWithError(new Exception("this is a test failure"));
        });
        return emitter;
    }

When calling this with curl, the response looks like:

HTTP/1.1 200 Content-Type: text/event-stream Transfer-Encoding:
chunked Date: Mon, 04 Nov 2024 12:50:10 GMT
data:this is a great first test
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

The send method behaves as expected. However, I would expect completeWithError to also send data, i.e. "this is a test failure", because this is my error message. Is my expectation wrong, or is this behaviour missing the error message?
